# How to write Pandas DataFrame to GCS in Parquet format?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write the BigQuery result into a parquet file to a GCS bucket of another project. The following code is hosted on Cloud Function and it works fine with writing CSV files but not parquet files

```
def main (data, context):
  bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
  blob_name = 'myfile.parquet'
  query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`"

  # project where the function is deployed
  client = bigquery.Client() 

  # access to the destination project using the key of the service account
  storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('secret.json') 

  destination_blob = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name).blob(blob_name)
  destination_blob.content_type = 'text/parquet'
  query_job = client.query(query)

  # couldn't manage to write anything into the parquet file
  query_job.result().to_dataframe().to_parquet(destination_blob.open('w'))
```

PS: The reason for using parquet format is that there are some nested fields in the BigQuery table

Comment: Hi @zZzZ, I have posted a solution for your requirements . Do consider to upvoting and accepting if it helps, else let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code as a workaround:

**First Approach:**

```
def main():
  bucket_name = 'destination_bucket'
  blob_name = 'myfile.parquet'
  destination_uri= f'gs://{bucket_name}/{blob_name}'
  query = "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`"
  client = bigquery.Client()
  query_job = client.query(query)
  query_job.result().to_dataframe().to_parquet(destination_uri)
```

In the above code I am using the url of the `cloud storage object` directly instead of using `destination_blob` .

**Second Approach:**

```
destination_bucket_name = "destination_bucket_name"
destination_blob_name = "myfile.parquet"
temporary_bucket_name="temporary_bucket_name"
temporary_blob_name="myfile.parquet"


def main(request):
  destination_uri= f'gs://{temporary_bucket_name}/{temporary_blob_name}'
  query = "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`"
  client = bigquery.Client()
  query_job = client.query(query)
  query_job.result().to_dataframe().to_parquet(destination_uri)
  status=copy()
  if status==1:
     return 'Completed'
  else:
     return 'Error'  

def copy():
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  temporary_bucket = storage_client.bucket(temporary_bucket_name)
  temporary_blob = temporary_bucket.blob(temporary_blob_name)
  storage_client_sorce = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('test.json')
  destination_bucket = storage_client_sorce.bucket(destination_bucket_name)
  blob_copy = destination_bucket.copy_blob( temporary_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name, )
  print( "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format( temporary_blob.name, temporary_bucket.name, blob_copy.name, destination_bucket.name, ) )
  temporary_blob.delete()
  return 1
```

In this second approach, I first fetch the bigquery data from the source project and convert it into a parquet file format. After that, I save that file in the source project bucket. In the second function, I copy that file from the source project to the destination project. After copying I delete the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Hi @zZzZ ,I have updated my answer.Before executing the above code make sure that you have the required permission.For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions).